# How can I record the date-time of entering data in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, powerbi, powerquery, powerpivot

I have many Excel sheets for production and quality information as below. All the records are collected to a single excel file through Power Query.

```
Product1-Datasheet
Production Time     Test Result
2021-06-01 12:05    Pass
2021-06-02 03:40    Pass
2021-06-18 19:30    Pass
...

Product2-Datasheet
Production Time     Test Result
2021-06-18 13:05    Pass
2021-06-22 23:35    Fail
2021-06-30 18:10    Pass
...
```

I would like to automatically record Test Time, which is the datetime when "Pass/Fail" are typed into the sheet by other users like this:

```
Product1-Datasheet
Production Time     Test Result     Test Time
2021-06-01 12:05    Pass            2021-06-02 01:36
2021-06-02 03:40    Pass            2021-06-03 05:56
2021-06-18 19:30    Pass            2021-06-20 00:52
...

Product2-Datasheet
Production Time     Test Result     Test Time
2021-06-18 13:05    Pass            2021-06-19 03:46
2021-06-22 23:35    Fail            2021-06-23 11:34
2021-06-30 18:10    Pass            2021-07-01 12:12
...
```

I am thinking about adding a new column in power query such as:

```
= Table.AddColumn(Source, "Test Time", each if [Test Result] <> null then DateTime.FixedLocalNow() else null)
```

But this can only record the time I refresh, not the time when the record is entered. Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the event procedure below. It must be installed in the code module of the worksheet on which you have your table, and the table must be a real Excel table, such as *Table1*. You are free and encouraged to give it another name but the code expressly refers to the first table in the worksheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' 285
    
    Const TestClm       As Long = 2     ' table column (Test): change to suit
    Const TimeClm       As Long = 3
    Dim R               As Long         ' changed table row
    
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub       ' skip if many cells are pasted
    
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, _
               .DataBodyRange.Columns(TestClm)) Is Nothing Then
            With .ListColumns
                If .Count < TimeClm Then
                    .Add
                    .Item(TimeClm).Range.Cells(1).Value = "Test time"
                End If
            End With
            
            R = Target.Row - .Range.Row
            With .DataBodyRange.Cells(R, TimeClm)
                .Value = Now()
                .NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm"
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

If installed in the correct code module the procedure will run automatically when a change is made to any cell in the table's second column (compare: `Const TestClm As Long = 2`). If the table still doesn't have a third column it will be added (compare: `Const TimeClm As Long = 3`). Then the current date and time will be written to the cell in column 3 of the row where the test result was entered or modified.

The above code differs from your idea in several ways. For one, it only adds a 3rd column if it doesn't exist. Two, it doesn't enter `Null` anywhere under any circumstances. Instead, it does nothing if it's not supposed to timestamp. Three, and most importantly, it enters the time stamp on every change, meaning the user can change the test result and the latest change's time will be recorded.

Comment: V can't you just change ListObjects(1) to ListObjects(2) if you want it to run on the second table?

Comment: @GMalc Of course. You could also specify the table by name.